# can't unbind custom handler from document.keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm binding my custom handler to `keydown` event of the `document:

```
this._bindCloseDlgEvents = function() {
    $(document).keydown(closeDlgByEscClick.bind(this));
};
```

I've checked and the event is bound: `$._data( document, "events" )` returns `{keydown: Array[1]}`.
Now I'm trying to unbind the same handler:

```
this._unbindCloseDlgEvents = function() {
    $(document).off('keydown', closeDlgByEscClick);
};
```

Checking with `$._data( document, "events" )` - nothing is changed `{keydown: Array[1]}`. 
Why so? If I unbind in this way `$(document).off('keydown')` the event is unbound, but I need to unbind only my specific handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using `.bind()` it returns a new anonymous function.

Use [namespaced event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) handler like

```
this._bindCloseDlgEvents = function() {
    $(document).on('keydown.closedialogevent', closeDlgByEscClick.bind(this));
};
```

then

```
this._unbindCloseDlgEvents = function() {
    $(document).off('keydown.closedialogevent');
};
```

[.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6H5YH/1/)